# Is a + on an email address a security vulnerability for a registration process?

Tags: email, registration

Is + in email addresses a security vulnerability for authentication algorithms? How can it be used in a malicious way? Should we forbid emails with + signs during registration?

For example we have 2 accounts that correspond to 2 different identities however they were registered with the same email address with + sign

Comment: Why would you think there was a security issue? It's a valid character in an email address. Are non-letter characters a surprise? There are a few valid special characters, like `.` too.

Comment: @schroeder if the platform requires having unique email addresses for each user it could be be exploited in a scenario when one email address corresponds to 2 different users

Comment: Same with `.` ... But that's not a security problem or vulnerability. That's just business logic in your program. You didn't know about the special characters and didn't account for them. That's a programming thing, not a security thing.

Comment: To handle it, you do with the email providers do: treat it as a valid string, but strip the special characters for internal handling ...

Comment: @schroeder I know. but also I know that gmail doesn't try to comply to RFC and considers a.b.c@gmail.com not equal to abc@gmail.com. therefore I think that for some companies it is a business logic flaw and a flaw in the RFC itself

Comment: Gmail definitely treats a.b.c@gmail.com the same as abc@gmail.com.  As @schroeder stated, you need to program in the business logic to account for the special characters.

Comment: There's no flaw or any problem. Just [exaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exaptation)

Comment: Do not deface your posts

Comment: @user228062: That is not "one email address".  It is two email addresses delivering into the same mailbox, and in general, that can happen between any two addresses and may change at any time.

Comment: @kenlukas: No, gmail does not treat them the same.  It treats one as an alias of the other, but it absolutely will preserve all the aliased addresses and you can write filters and rules that distinguish.

Comment: @BenVoigt "alias"? Do you mean that in an RFC way?

Answer (score 8):

This sounds a bit like an XY problem. You could block the use of a `+` sign in emails on the basis that *some* providers use this for subaddressing. But there are still lots of other things that a user can do, including:

- Adding periods or other characters to the address that their mailserver ignores (as other have suggested).
- Registering multiple emails like `user1@example.org` and `user2@example.org`.
- Creating aliases so that `user1@example.org` and `user2@example.org` both point to the same mailbox.
- Creating a wildcard so that `*@example.org` points to one mailbox.
- Registering using a shared account like `contact@example.org`, or sharing the password for their email with multiple other individuals.
- Registering using a free email provider that doesn't require passwords.

Ultimately, you cannot guarantee that an email address corresponds to a single individual, and you cannot guarantee that an individual person only has a single email address.

As an example, imagine you get three accounts registered:

- `user.name@example.org`
- `username@example.org`
- `username+stuff@example.org`

Unless you know the exact configuration of my mailserver, there is no way that you can know whether those addresses correspond to one, two or three mailboxes. And there's also no way that you can know how many individuals have access to each of those mailboxes.

So on that basis, I don't see how blocking the use of a `+` sign in email addresses will help, unless your application is unable to process them. But then it's not clear exactly what the *security* problem that you are trying to solve is.

Answer (score 0):

The use of a plus sign `+` in an email address is a useful feature. Gmail, as well as many other mail providers will deliver mail addressed to `user+tag@example.com` as though it were addressed to `user@example.com`.

The `+tag` portion of the email address can then be used both for purposes like registration and filtering emails into the inbox.

It's very useful when a user is trying to find out the source of spam emails and can use it to block any future correspondence from the spam provider or organize the emails with **Tags / Folders**.

> How can it be used in a malicious way?

The only way it can be used maliciously is by multiple sign-up spam or user registrations.

Most of the providers do have security measures to prevent signup spams from automated bots/scripts like: rate-limiting, captcha, etc. So, if you have these measures already in place, you are ok.

> Should we forbid emails with + signs during registration?

It depends on the specific business use case. If it requires a user to register only once, you can check for it during registration and if an account already exists with any variant (`user<*>@example.com`), then you might disallow this with something like:

"User already exists with that email."

Comment: Your process works for `+tag` appended to the end of the account name, but that doesn't address the bigger issue. `u.s.e.r@example.com` is the same as `user@example.com`. Instead, as I said in comments, you should strip those characters and added bits for internal handling.

Comment: Hold on, isn't this `+tag` and `u.s.e.r` behaviour dependant on the mail server and its implementation? I know Gmail for example does the first one, but I think my own mail server doesn't do that (I think, I'm not sure). I just want to clarify and not attack or something like that..

Comment: @SirMuffington it obviously depends on the configuration of the mail provider. If you host your own using postfix, you're going to have different results. But since the Answer chose Gmail as an example, then the bigger issue needs to be addressed (no pun intended), too.